# The inputAccessoryView and the bottom of safe area is overlapped in certain models of iphone

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitoolbar, inputaccessoryview

Here is the picture of the certain models of iphone where the toolbar is overlapping the line in the bottom of the iphone (not sure what it is).

The toolbar is attaching to the keyboard (input accessory) and if the keyboard disappears then the toolbar will be at the bottom of the iphone and the textview will expand or inpand upon the will of keyboard. I didn't set any constraints for the toolbar. I expect the toolbar to adhere the safe area. Any idea to to get the toolbar above the safe area for all of the models?

I managed to get the toolbar container to adhere to the safe area but it looks weird - the background of the toolbar has grey and the background didn't move up together.

[image]

Here are the constraints I have - I can't drag the toolbar to safe area, just for only toolbar container (stackview).

[image]

I tried doing this below but it says I did it illegally and tried doing for the toolbar.

```
inputAccessoryView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Here is the initialization for the inputAccessoryView -

```
override var inputAccessoryView:UIView{
        get {
            return self.toolbar
        }
}
```

The toolbar is located in the storyboard -

[image]

The toolbar has checked "use Safe Area LayoutGuides"

The issue is in the bottom of the screen -

[image]